# modify string by passing address in c++

Tags: c++, string

I want to modify the string variable present in main function by the external function, by passing the address of the same.

Below is the code which I've written

```
void change(char * str)
{
    str="Max";
}

void main() 
{    
    char a[]="Test";
    change(a);

    cout<<a;
}
```

Please correct me if I am wrong

Please note that I am using Borland Turbo C++ 4.5.

Comment: Show us what you've already done. As it stands, you may as well be asking: "friends, show me how to draw feeling!" or "friends, show me how to taste a color!"

Comment: why are you using the pre-standard turbo c++ 4.5?

Comment: You're using [what](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-UUsp4BjOE94/TtHQqVD0g4I/AAAAAAAABaE/kVvgJrJvE_Q/s1600/6950119214.jpg)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
void change(char * str)
{
    strcpy(str,"Max");
}
```

Recall what a pointer is, and that the pointer itself cannot be changed only what it points to.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you mean pass by reference, you can simply pass the given string by reference to the external function as follows:

```
void modifyString( string& str)
{
   //modify the string
}
```

inside `main`, you can call this function.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not use Turbo C/C++, It was last updated long time ago,

You can change a string in a function as follows,

```
void change(char * str)
{
   *(str+0)='M';
   *(str+1)='A';
   *(str+2)='X';
   *(str+3)='\0';
}

int main() 
{
  char a[]="Hello";
  change(a) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask,

> “correct me if i am wrong”

after presenting this code:

```
void change(char * str)
{
  str="Max";
}

void main() {

char a[]="Test";
change(a);
cout<<a;
}
```

So, here goes:

- `str="Max";`
  only changes the local pointer `str`. with a compiler conforming to the C++11 standard it won’t even compile, because `str` is declared as `char*` while the literal `"Max"` is of type `char const [4]`, and C++11 does not anymore support an implicit conversion from string literal to pointer to non-`const`.
- `void main`
  will not compile with any standard-conforming C or C++ compiler, no matter which standard. however, visual c++ will compile it with no diagnostic. and possibly old turbo c++ did too, but note that turbo c++ *predated* the first C++ standard (which came in 1998). the standard requires `int` result type for `main` for an ordinary hosted C++ implementation.
- `cout<<a;`
  will not compile with a standard-conforming compiler without including `<iostream>` and having a `using` declaration or directive. note that this changed with the standardization. before the 1998 standard, in ARM C++, you could include `<iostream.h>` and use unqualified `cout`.

A proper way to do your program, in modern C++, is

```
#include <iostream>    // std::cout, std::endl
#include <string>      // std::string
using namespace std;

string foo() { return "Max"; }

int main()
{
    string a = "Test";
    a = foo();    // Changed!
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

[another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15915735/464581), which as I’m writing this you have selected as “solution”, recommends using raw pointers and `strcpy`, instead of **`std::string`**. using raw pointers and arrays is advice that will make you unhappy if you follow it. for example, it’s very easy to inadvertently write beyond the end of the provided buffer, with disastrous effects. ownership handling is exceedingly difficult to do correctly, and so on. the advice was presumably given in the Stack Overflow tradition of *answering the literal question* with no regard for what the question was really about, which is a good way to obtain Stack Overflow reputation points (it beats me what is so desirable about them, the silly T-shirts or whatever are really not worth it), at the cost of creating severe problems for others, sort of like maiming a few bystanders in order to steal a small bar of chocolate.